# What Percentage of Crashes Get Reported?

Tags: android, google-play, crash-reports

Does anyone have any figures or rule of thumb in how to interpret crash report figures in terms of number of actual people affected, specifically those given on the Google Play Developer accounts?

My understanding is that a crash is only reported if a person clicks report after the crash and I wonder what percentage of people actually do.

I am very new to Android and my app is used by about 70 people, I have had one crash report in an earlier version of my app, but does that mean that only one person has had a problem in a rare situation or that it is just the tip of the iceberg and a fair bit of energy should be focused on correcting it?

I have not been able to find this information elsewhere but I assume people here must have a rough idea.

EDITED: apologies for the question being too broad, but I now know the answer is that bug reporting varies a lot depending on several factors, that many bugs don't get recorded, and that what I should be doing is using something like Google Analytics or BugSense rather than trying to guess based on crash reports submitted.

Comment: I don't think this question can be properly answered; there are just too many variables. For example, if you make a kids game that crashes frequently, I have a hard time believing that the children will report the crash. On the other hand, if you make a stackoverflow interface, I bet the vast majority of the crashes will be reported with a number of possible fixes and useful messages to fix the issue.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA thank you, you make a good point, I should be more specific, it is an app for professionals. I agree that there will be a lot of variables and any answer will not be exact, but while saying that the question can't be answered properly you have gone some way in answering it by specifying types of apps that are likely to have high or low reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my first year or so as an Android developer maintaining an inherited project, I'd get most of my bug reports via customer service.  Usually they'd be vague.  If I was really lucky I'd get a log.  I'd figure out how to reproduce the problem and cut a new build.  I'd follow up with customer service, and the feedback would be that the customer was very happy with it.

Then I found out about BugSense.  Now I'm astounded by customers' low standards.  The vast majority of crashes (well over 95%) are never reported to customer service.  The flip side is that after fixing over 90% of the crashes, no customer has ever commented on the improvement.

Comment: Thanks, good to know your experience as well as something I can use to get more accurate figures

Answer (score 1):

If you want in depth crash reports and ANRs (Application not responding), you need to implement google analytics into your app. Otherwise, only reported crashes will be able to be seen in the developer console.

Comment: Agreed. If OP will need to do this to catch any application crashes that are not reported.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion, will implement that. I accepted the other answer though as I valued the person sharing their experience of bug reporting in addition to mentioning something I could use to get better data.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a few different crashes reported to me by my users. This was because of [ACRA](https://code.google.com/p/acra/). It writes the stack of errors as an email and presents it to the user who has the option of sending the email or discarding it. Very useful IMHO.

But then again, it does not change the fact that it is upto the users discretion. So percentage wise I doubt if anyone can give you a number.